# Remote multi-user database access through internet

Tags: python, database, software-design

Please bear with me, because I am quite new to this.
I would like to make a software which can access and interact with data which is stored on a local pc. The access goes through the internet.

Basically, I would like to create a database on a local machine which a software on another pc (connected through the internet) can access and interact with. Also this pc should be able to send some data back to the data-hosting pc.

[image]

I have never done this, so I am missing key terms to search for on Google:

1. What database system should be used on the data-host pc (preferably free and open source)  ?
2. How do you access and interact with that data through the internet ? 
   I was thinking of programing the software using python

Thank you so much for any hint ! 
I suppose that what I am looking for is a client server model.

Comment: Unless you want to open up your router's firewall (which I would not recommend until you really know what you're doing, and what you could be letting yourself into...), you'll have to pay for hosting. By going for a passive server model, you could still store the data on your pc, but despite that, you'd need an external device that can store and forward messages to and from the client.... Unless the client and server are on the same LAN, you should probably go for a website that you can use PHP and SQL to interact with...

Comment: In terms of database structure, depending on the data you want to store, using SQL and PHP to interact with a .db file is probably the best way forward. w3schools have great tutorials to get you started...

Comment: @EdWard Thank you very much for your comments ! Concerning PHP, I could also use Python, right ? I am just much more familiar with that language than PHP. Could I use SQL Light (because open source and free) on the data server and the Diago Web framework to build the website ?

Comment: You can certainly use Python with Django on your own machine, but if you don't want the risks of port forwarding to your own network, you'd have to check if server hosting companies would allow you to run your Python script... I'm not sure if such services exist... If not, you can go down passive route where the client can request information, and when your Python script connects to the server, it tells the script that the client wants information. The script can then send the info. The client checks back later on to see if it has arrived yet...

Comment: Also, depending on what kind of system you want the end user to see, could you use FTP? That way your client script could just be a connection to your port-forwarded server, and it could take a copy of the files (with a password) without you having to write the server back end...

Comment: @EdWard Thank you for your further advice. FTP surely sounds also interesting. Maybe, let me tell you a bit more about what I need: I will have a big dataset (so downloading the dataset onto every client pc will not be an option) on one side, and a software on the other side which will use part of the data to run computations locally on the client pc. So the client will basically choose which data he needs and what computation to do, the software will pull that data from the database and run the computation.